# Does Quantum Theory allow an Electron to take a fraction of Photon energy

Tags: photons, electrons, collision, wave-particle-duality, photoelectric-effect

In Photoelectric Effect of Theory of Spectral Lines , an electron takes the entire or none of the energy of the Photon ( it absorbs the entire quanta not its fractionS resulting in the disappearance of the Photon).

*But in Compton Effect the Electron takes only a fraction of the Photon Energy and the Photon stays alive.*

*What I specifically want to know is that Quantum theory says that an electron will either take the whole or none of the Photon energy .*

*Why then in Compton Effect the electron takes a fraction of the Photon energy* Is that allowed by Quantum theory ?

**Or is not so ? Or the electron takes up 1  photon only when in an energy level . When an electron is free , can it absorb half the energy of a photon ?**

Edit:

**I still don't get whether the electrons are allowed to take the energy of the whole photon when they are in energy levels and can they absorb a fraction of the photon energy when they are free.**

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/231173/what-is-basic-difference-between-photoelectric-effect-and-compton-effect and http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/31581/compton-scattering-vs-photoelectric-effect?rq=1

Comment: @Countto10  But the question is why for  a bound electron it is Photoelectric Effect and for free electron its Compton Effect

Comment: Hi, my references are not meant as duplicates,sorry, just as background. What is annoying me is I wrote an answer to almost this question some time ago, but  the search engine here does not list it, if I can find it on Google I will list it.

Comment: @Countto10  Yes please . If you can find the answer please list it. What I specifically want to know is that Quantum theory says that an electron will either take the whole or none of the energy . Why then here it takes a fraction of the Photon energy

Comment: I think it has to do that compton is a scattering, i.e. the photon and electron are scattered. On the feynman diagram, there is absorption of a virtual photon, so indeed the electron absorbs a "whole" photon. In the photoelectric effect I'd say that since the electron is not free, scattering cannot happen, but I'm not sure about that and how to justify it.

Comment: @Frotaur But an electron can only take whole or none of the energy of the photon no in fractions. That is the basis of quanta. But here the Electron has actually taken only a fraction of photon energy. So is it false that electrons absorb only a full photon

Comment: I have to correct, I meant to say a virtual electron on my previous comment. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1Z0h.png . This is the underlying process of a compton scattering. It is mediated through a virtual particle (an electron). As you can see, the photon is fully absorbed at the vertices of the interaction, as you require, and then re-emitted.

However, I don't know why this interaction would be forbidden in the case of the photoelectric effect.

Comment: @Frotaur  I haven't learn't feynMan diagrams. All I wanted to know in terms of the basic quanta is that can electrons take a fraction of energy of the photon ?

Comment: I don't know if you can justify it that way, but you could go on and say that in a compton scattering the photon absorbs the whole photon, then re-emits a photon but in a different direction and with different energy. This is not actually how it happens but I guess it kind of justify it.

Comment: @Frotaur Ok. Let's wait if anyone wishes to answer it. I don't understand why it is not being answered. Its not that bad a question either .

Comment: @Countto10 Hi! Could you please if you wish tell me whether my comment on PhillS's answer to this question is right or not. If it's not right can you please tell what's wrong

Comment: I think your Edit is correct and pretty much a good summary of the answers. Have you received confirmation for your "Edit" yet. My hint is to look at the colours - only certain frequencies are accepted and totally absorbed when it gets black.

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/364967/should-electrons-always-absorb-all-the-energy-from-a-photon?rq=1)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that a photon cannot transmit its total energy to a free electron. Contradiction with Photoelectric effect?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/174051/show-that-a-photon-cannot-transmit-its-total-energy-to-a-free-electron-contradi)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I still don't get whether the electrons are allowed to take the energy of the whole photon when they are in energy levels and can they absorb a fraction of the photon energy when they are free

Electrons may be free, or bound within an atom due to the relative potential between the  nucleus and the electron, for a simple case, i.e. the hydrogen atom.

When bound in an atom a photon with an exact energy difference ( within the width) to the ionization level can be completely absorbed by the atomic system and an electron will go free and the atom will recoil. This kinematically is a two body situation. Before it is "photon + atom" after "electron + atom". There exists a physical center of mass system.

In two body interactions energy and momentum are conserved by the end particles, in this case an ionized atom and an electron.

When an electron is free , as in compton scattering, the system is "Photon1 + electron" as initial state, and the final state is "photon2+electron" There exists a consistent physical center of mass system in both cases.

Energy and momentum are conserved from initial to final state.

If photon2 is a zero vector, the initial center of mass will have the invariant mass of "photon1+electron" which will be larger than just the mass of the electron, and the final one will have just the invariant mass of the electron. This is inconsistent with energy conservation and cannot be physical.

> And how energy and Momentum will not be conserved when the bound electron is hit by a photon of energy less than the energy difference between any two consecutive cells and then the electron gets out of its shell

In quantum mechanics, the atom is a bound system to which energy can be given in quanta, corresponding to the energy levels.

If the transition is "Photon + atom" going to "excited atom", i.e. the electron changed energy level, energy is conserved because now the atom has more energy, the one the photon gave up. In the center of mass before, momentum is zero, and after momentum is zero and the energy before is equal to the energy after *because **the atom** is at an excited level* carrying the photon energy.

The case of photon +electron ---> electron cannot conserve energy, because at the center of mass there is the energy of the photon +the energy of the mass of the electron, incoming, but only the energy of the mass of the electron outgoing, *the  electron does not have  quantum mechanical excited states* to increase its rest mass energy, as the excited atom does.

Comment: You mean to say that an electron will absorb a part of the photon's energy only when it is free. When it is bound in an atomic shell it will absorb the all photon's energy ( the the difference being equal to the difference in two. successive energy State , again energy conservation). This is all because of the conservation laws. So the electron which is in a shell can absorb a full photon only because then the conservation laws will be true . So it's necessary for an electron in an orbit to absorb a full photon so that energy conservation can be true is that right ?

Comment: If yes....Then when x rays are allowed to fall on a metal like in a compton scattering experiment then there should be both  Compton scattering and Photoelectric effect taking place because in a metal there will be both bound and free electrons....

Comment: Actually it is the system that absorbs the energyy in the bound case, not just the electron .The atom is a whole system, the absorbed photon energy kicks out the electron and the (diminshed)atom recoils ( though the difference in the masses makes this recoil very small).

Comment: electrons are bound in the metal, they are bound to the lattice as a whole, in energy levels  see http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Solids/band.html . http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod2.html

Comment: If you look at this table http://www.colby.edu/chemistry/PChem/notes/AOIE.pdf you will see that the atomic binding energies are many electron volts, but the work function in the second link above is less than 1 ev. in the beginning of the line. It is the binding in the conduction band of the electrons.

Comment: So it's all because of conservation laws . In one case the electron atom system absorb a full photon to allow the electron to go the higher level. In the other case the free electron absorbs a part of the photon energy only. Both are a result of conservation laws , specifically energy. It's nothing special that in one case full photon is taken up , in the other only a bit. It is because conservation is a necessity. Is that right , what I have got    ?

Comment: Yes, conservation of energy and momentum are the important definers of what is physical in interactions and what is not.

Comment: Thanks a lot . I hope my future questions could be seen by you !!

Comment: Could you please add how & why will energy and momentum be conserved in the case of a bound electron being hit by a photon of energy equal to the energy difference between two consecutive cells and then the electron jumping to the next  energy level . And how energy and Momentum  will not be conserved when the bound electron is hit by a photon of energy less than the energy difference between any two consecutive cells and then the electron gets out of its shell (it cannot reach the higher shell offcourse but goes somewhere.

Comment: in Compton scattering 9 questions are derived keeping in mind the conservation laws but I want to see why the conservation laws will not hold true in one case and will hold true in the other case in the above example ? I tried but I couldn't? I hope I have made the question clear

Comment: I have edited   the answer

Comment: Ok thank you ! I got it! Will you like to have a look at this. It's quite genuine a question. I want to to know that can there be any other reasoning apart of the 1st answer there https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/311606/113699

Comment: For this too - Is that the only reasoning. For this one I guess the answer is the correct one but I want to check. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/300551/113699 But the 1st one is quite puzzling

Comment: Could you please tell me what  would be the nature of an electron seen by another electron moving with the same velocity ( since both have the same velocity ) Will it be particle like or wavelike and whether i should go ahead of posting this question. Because I feel  it is a dumb question. And my recent question wasn't well received so I want to know whether i should go ahead and post this question or is too dumb to be asked?

Comment: electrons are elementary point particles. They are described by a wave function whose square gives the probability of where the electron is. It is the probability, the accumulation of measurements that has a wavy nature. Two electrons "know" each other through their common interaction wave function . see this for two negative electrons: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/expar.html , the third page.

Comment: you say " accumulation of measurements" that has a wavy nature. But that would mean that it's our experimental fault. The electron can exist as a particle only. Our apparatus isn't good enough detect a particle . Like a one photon experiment. Each photon hits the screen at one point. It is the histogram of these hits which seen after a while looks like a diffraction pattern. But actually it's made of hits by a full photon only. Couldn't it be that  it's is our inability ( apparatus). Because an electron or photon never has both behaviour at the same time.

Comment: People have tried to find theories that would show such a statistical behavior from underlying dynamics. They faile. At best , like the Bohm pilot model, they reproduce some aspect but have no new testable predictions and fail for high relativistic energies and the complexity of the data. We are forced to accept a basic quantum mechanical probabilistic duality:  the instance of measurement macroscopically looks like a classical point, the statistical accumulation shows a wave behavior, as an underlying axiom of physics. i.e. quantum mechanics

Comment: Ok thank you I am getting it. I will go ahead and ask a question with certain addendums. Could you suggest a book apart from Griffiths to begin Quantum Mechanic with a better intuitive outlook ....

Comment: Sorry, I am much removed in years from the educational process. I learned quantum mechanics from schiff and Merzbaher. http://www.fisica.net/quantica/ebooks/MERZBACHER%20-%20Quantum%20Mechanics%202ed.pdf

Answer (score 6):

There is a simple reason why a free election can't absorb a photon completely: you can't conserve both energy and momentum for the system of you start off with an electron and a photon and and up with only an electron. You need a final photon as well for conservation of energy and momentum to be satisfied.

For the photoelectric effect things are different. We don't have a free electron ; it is bound to a nucleus. Consequently it can only have certain precise energy values (and won't interact with photons that would move it to a non existent energy level, which is the basic argument for quantum behaviour, but not really comparable to Compton scattering).

In the situation analagous to Compton scattering, the photon has more energy than the binding energy of the electron, and so we wind up with a free electron. But in this case energy and momentum can be conserved without a final photon since the nucleus is also involved in the interaction. The initial state is {photon,  bound electron,  nucleus } and the final state {free electron,  nucleus}.

It is possible to construct Feynman diagrams with a final photon present too, but since they have an extra vertex they happen less often by a factor of roughly the fine structure constant $\alpha\sim\frac{1}{137}.$

Or to put it another way,  sometimes in the photoelectric effect where you end up with a free electron you *do* get a final photon, but it is in less than 1% of cases (unless I've overlooked some reason why it can't happen).

Comment: 2 questions - Firstly the absorption of a full photon ( the basis of Bohr theory) is only valid for the Electron bound in a shell because it can be only in certain energy levels. And a free electron need not take the full energy of the photon because because it is not constrained to Move in certain energy levels. Is my understanding is right ? Secondly Compton effect is for free electron and photo electric for bound one. But in the photo electric , the Electron ultimately becomes free whereas in Compton the Electron is bound . So the 1 reasoning still ok

Comment: @Phillis Isn't the graph of absorbance of photon vs photon frequency going to have some troughs, for the material's quantum behaviour?

Comment: Does the first paragraph of the answer refer to: "...Thomson scattering 

is the elastic scattering of electromagnetic radiation by a free charged particle (...) It is the low-energy limit of Compton scattering: the particle's kinetic energy and photon frequency do not change as a result of the scattering..."  Conversely (cp. Wikipedia), impulse is being transmitted from/by the photon to the free electrion if photon's energy is high enough.  It should not contradict  the principle of conservation of energy if all the energy of the photon becomes/is turned into momentum of the electron.